# How to display column and stacked column bars in a chart in Einstein Analytics?

Tags: dashboard, analytics, charts, einstein

**Description:**

Einstein Analytics dashboards contains different chart types to select. Column and stacked column charts are only two out of tens available.

[image: Column Chart]

[image: Stacked Column Chart]

**Question**

Is it possible to use column bars and stacked column bars **in one chart** like in the figure below?

[image: Column and Stacked Column bars in one chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I managed to get two columns side by side with the actual data. Here I use SAQL statements to load the data and transform it into two sets (targeted revenue and actual revenue) then union both sets while setting the null values to 0, lastly order them by year and sum of values of both sets side by side. Additional steps require use of 'stacked column' charts while keeping year on the horizontal axis, sums in vertical axis and stacking the values by status (high, medium, low) and setting the axis mode to 'single'. Final data table looks like this.
[image]